# How to draw a path between two nodes using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a set of lat and long points which form a route from source to destination. I have used polyline method of Leaflet to draw the path between the source to destination, but it gives a scrambled path.

```
      var firstpolyline = new L.polyline(latlong, {
      color: 'red',
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 0.5,
      smoothFactor: 1

      });
      firstpolyline.addTo(mym[![enter image description here][1]][1]ap);
```

The **latlong** in the above code is an array of latitude and longitude points. But it gives a scrambled output like this:

[image: polyline forming scrambled output]imgur.com/aZrGa.jpg

But the latlong points form a single correct path from source to destination. I have been using polyLine. What mistake am I doing? Should I use some other methods of Leaflet?

### Edit after @ivansanchez comment

The latlong arrays are of type L.LatLng(x,y) where L is the Leaflet object. Here is a snippet:

[image]

Comment: How does your array of `LatLng`s look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake, Polyline works properly. I had an array of latlng that were not in an order. Putting an ordered latlng points helped me plot the route correctly between source and destination.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// 1. 
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([17.387140, 78.491684], 13);
// 2. 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: "&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
}).addTo(mymap); 
// 3. 
var latlngs = [
    [15.89625,80.53544],
    [15.89626,80.53542],
    [15.89628,80.53536],
    [15.89617,80.53539],
    [15.89621,80.53547]
]; 
// 4. 
var path = L.polyline.antPath(
    latlngs,
    {"delay":400,"dashArray":[10,20],"weight":5,"color":"black","paused":true,"reverse":false}
).addTo(mymap);
// 5. 
mymap.addLayer(path);
mymap.fitBounds(path.getBounds());
```

### EXPLANATION:

1. To set the map view on given latlongs([17.387140, 78.491684]), 13 means zoom.
2. Adding tiles on the maps.
3. Latlongs.
4. Drawing polylines ant paths by setting css.
5. Add the layer to the path.

Comment: Code only answers are good. Please add some explanation to it.

Comment: If polyline was used, we can draw only straight line. If polyline.antPath was used, we can draw path including all the latlongs.i.e.,curves also.

Comment: Edit the answer, and add the details to the answer itself

Comment: polyline works fine without the addition of 'antPath'